# Localytics android push message notification sound

Tags: android, notifications, localytics

I have integrated localytics and localytics push notifications in my app. However when the push message arrives, the notification is shown with the system default sound. How do I change that to a custom sound? Sound is a bit essential to the branding of my app so I'd really like to do this.

I searched the localytics docs and there's sound config for iOS but I couldn't find it for Android

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
Localytics.setPushNotificationOptions(new PushNotificationOptions.Builder()
                .setSound(Uri.parse("YOUR_MP3FILE"))
                .build());
```

Comment: However, I find that this works unreliably. I think that it's not really saving the options and they're set only in memory. Any help?